# Import Xcode project into SCM / Subversion without duplicating project

Tags: svn, xcode, version-control

### Is there any way to click on something that Adds whole project to SCM/Subversion and also makes it a working directory by adding .svn folders?

I create an XCode project as usual.
Is the any way to just get Xcode to add the project to Subversion without import and checking out to a separate folder.
My problem is that I have a /Dev folder that I create my XCode projects in.
I create a new project under this e.g. /Dev/MyProject

I import the project into Subversion using SCM/ Repositories/Import.

This doesnt create the /Dev/MyProject/.svn folder until I do SCM/ Repositories/ Checkout

The problem now is I either have to check out to another folder
e.g. /Dev/MyProject1

or else checkout complains folders aren't versioned.

Two solutions I can find is create my project in tmp dir then import it and do checkout into /Dev/MyProject
or create project/ import it/ delete it / check it out to same folder
...seems clunky.
Any way to click on something that Adds whole project to SCM/Subersion and also makes it a working directory by adding .svn folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you import your project into Subversion, run

```
svn checkout --force svn://path/to/MyProject /Dev/MyProject
```

at the command line (replacing `svn://path/to/MyProject` with the appropriate protocol and path).  That will turn your existing project into a working copy.